# Return rows only if matches all list values

Tags: sql, where-clause

Let's say I have a table `customers`:

`-----------------`
`|id|name|country|`
`|1 |Joe |Mexico |` 
`|2 |Mary|USA    |` 
`|3 |Jim |France |` 
`-----------------`

And a table `languages`:

`-------------`
`|id|language|`
`|1 |English |` 
`|2 |Spanish |` 
`|3 |French  |` 
`-------------`

And a table `cust_lang`:

`------------------`
`|id|custId|langId|`
`|1 |1     |1     |` 
`|2 |1     |2     |` 
`|3 |2     |1     |` 
`|4 |3     |3     |` 
`------------------`

Given a list: ["English", "Spanish", "Portugese"]
Using a `WHERE IN` for the list, it will still return customers with ids 1,2 because they match "English" and "Spanish".
However, the results should be 0 rows returned since no customer matches ALL three terms.
I only want the customer ids to return if it matches the cust_lang table.
For instance, Given a list: ["English", "Spanish"]
I would want the results to be customer Id 1, since he alone speaks both languages.

EDIT: @GordonLinoff - That works!!

Now to make it more complex, what's wrong with this additional related query:

Let's assume I also have a table `degrees`:

`-----------`
`|id|degree|`
`|1 |PHD   |` 
`|2 |BA    |` 
`|3 |MD    |` 
`-----------`

A corresponding join table `cust_deg`:

`------------------`
`|id|custId|degId |`
`|1 |1     |1     |` 
`|2 |1     |2     |` 
`|3 |2     |1     |` 
`|4 |3     |3     |` 
`------------------`

The following query does not work. However, it is two of the same queries combined. The results should be only rows that match both lists, instead of the one list.

```
SELECT * FROM customers C
    WHERE C.id IN (
    SELECT CL.langId FROM cust_lang CL
    JOIN languages L on CL.langId = L.id 
    WHERE L.language IN ("English", "Spanish")
    GROUP BY CL.langID 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) 
AND C.id IN (
        SELECT CD.custId FROM cust_deg CD
        JOIN degrees D ON CD.degID = D.id 
        WHERE D.degree IN ("PHD", "BA") 
        GROUP BY CD.custId HAVING COUNT(*) = 2));`
```

EDIT2: I think i fixed it. I accidentally had an extra select statement in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select cl.custid
from cust_lang cl join
     languages l
     on cl.langid = l.id
where l.language in ('English', 'Spanish', 'Portuguese')
group by cl.custid
having count(*) = 3;
```

If, for example, you only wanted to check for two languages, then you need only change you `WHERE ... IN` and `HAVING` conditions, e.g.:

```
where l.language in ('English', 'Spanish')
```

and

```
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: This works if we correct the `where` to `l.language`

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much Gordon's answer but it has the benefit of being a little more flexible on the language list and it doesn't require any change to the `having` clause.

```
with my_languages as (
    select langId from languages
    where language in ('English', 'Spanish')
)
select cl.custId
from cust_lang as cl inner join my_languages as l on l.langId = cl.langId
group by cl.custId
having count(*) = (select count(*) from lang)
```