# How to select products in specific categories using SQL query in WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I used below code to select products from specific categories and works fine but I want to select products if include more than one category

```
SELECT post.ID, post.post_title FROM  `wp_posts` as post

INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.object_id = post.ID 
WHERE
post.`post_type` IN ('product','product_variation') 
AND tr.term_taxonomy_id  IN(32,25)
```

I use `IN(32,25)` and it returns all products, how can I filter products just included in two categories?

Comment: `GROUP BY 1,2 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tr.term_taxonomy_id) = 2`

Answer (score 3):

To query products that are in specific categories (e.g. categories with the ids of 32 and 35), you could use this:

```sql
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND 
( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (32,35) ) 
AND 
wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND 
(wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY 
wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY 
wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

It's recommended to use `global $wpdb` and take advantage of

- `$wpdb->prefix` for your wordpress table "prefix", instead if hard coding "wp_"

and

- `$wpdb->prepare` for security.

Like this:

```php
global $wpdb;

$query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}posts.* FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships 
    ON ({$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id) 
    WHERE 1=1 
    AND 
    ( {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (32,35) ) 
    AND 
    {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'product' 
    AND 
    ({$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_status = 'publish') 
    GROUP BY 
    {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID 
    ORDER BY 
    {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date DESC"
);

$sql_results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
```

---

**For security reasons, avoid writing your own `sql queries` as much as possible.**

In order to query your database try to use:

- [`wp_query`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

or

- [`wc_get_product`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-product-functions.html#function_wc_get_products)

Comment: thanks for your information but if i used `{$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (32,35)` all product include in this two categories listed. I just want to return the existing products in both categories. in some case maybe just include in one of them

Comment: @EhsanRavanbakhsh check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38135711/1533148 you could get the count using PHP and pass that in to the prepared statement.

Comment: @Ruvee what is the WHERE 1=1  for?

Comment: @KevinChavez I think that's just for making condition true